# Pan audio in cordova (play only out of left / right headphone)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins

Are there any libraries for panning audio left or right in Cordova/Phonegap/Ionic? Ideally, I would like to have a sound file and play it out of either the left or right headphone channel but not both.

I have looked at the cordova-media-plugin, cordova-native-audio, cordovoa-audioToggle, and soundJS/createJS. Of these, only soundJS & createJS seems to be able to control the headphone output and panning, but it doesn't seem like it works with Cordova. Also there are no examples for angular / cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android 6.0, the following script works. It makes use of the Web Audio API. I have not yet tested it on iOS, but I have a good feeling it will work there (please comment if it does not).

You need an "omg.mp3" file in your root directory to test with. You also should build using Cordova and not worry about the CORS or Same-domain error you might get in your browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>StereoPannerNode example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>StereoPannerNode example</h1>
    <audio controls>  
      <source src="omg.mp3" type="audio/mp3">   
      <p>Browser too old to support HTML5 audio? How depressing!</p>
    </audio>
    <h2>Set stereo panning</h2>
    <input class="panning-control" type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" value="0">
    <span class="panning-value">0</span>

  </body>
<script>
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var myAudio = document.querySelector('audio');

var panControl = document.querySelector('.panning-control');
var panValue = document.querySelector('.panning-value');


// Create a MediaElementAudioSourceNode
// Feed the HTMLMediaElement into it
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);

// Create a stereo panner
var panNode = audioCtx.createStereoPanner();

// Event handler function to increase panning to the right and left
// when the slider is moved

panControl.oninput = function() {
  panNode.pan.value = panControl.value;
  panValue.innerHTML = panControl.value;
}

// connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the gainNode
// and the gainNode to the destination, so we can play the
// music and adjust the panning using the controls
source.connect(panNode);
panNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  </script>
</html>
```